# cannot convert long to IEnumerable<long>

Tags: c#

I have created a method as follows. I want to pass the parameter of long into this method by converting it into IEnumerable. I tried casting but it is not working. I couldn't find a solution for this. I have attatched my method below.

`public static IEnumerable<long> GetDetail(IEnumerable<long> x, IEnumerable<long> y){}`

Comment: But which is the porpouse of this method? Merge the two IEnumerable?

Comment: @MarcoBeninca this method will check whether y has the details which x contains

Comment: Use LINQ to do that `return y.Where(e => x.Contains(e));`

Comment: I need a way to convert a long value to IEnumerable<long> and pass that as the parameter

Comment: IEnumerable is just an interface, you need a concrete implementation of it... you can do the following `IEnumerable details = GetDetail(new List<long>() { 1 }, new List<long> { 2 }); `